# How to add Oracle database url with SSL attributes in mule?

Tags: oracle, spring-jdbc, anypoint-studio, ojdbc, mule-esb

I want to know how to set oracle JDBC url with ssl properties in mule esb.

for mysql I came to know that we can have the url like below

**jdbc:mysql://hostname:port/dataService?useSSL=true&requireSSL=true&verifyServerCertificate=true&trustCertificateKeyStoreUrl=file:\\C:\Users\ad\localhost-truststore.jks&trustCertificateKeyStorePassword=xyxyxy**

For oracle can we add the properties like above (requireSSL, verifyServerCertificate, trustCertificateKeystore etc..) in url ?

The url that I have now is

**jdbc:oracle:thin:${oracledb.userName}/${oracledb.password}@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCPS)(HOST=${oracledb.host})(PORT=${oracledb.port}))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=${oracledb.service})))**

Answer (score 0):

For Oracle JDBC driver, you can use TNSalias and add your long form of the connection URL with certificate etc., in tnsnames.ora. Later, use the property oracle.net.tns_admin=/home/myuser/cloud to specify the location of tnsnames.ora. 
If you are using the latest 18.3 JDBC driver then you can pass TNS_ADMIN as part of the URL along with the TNSAlias. 
jdbc:oracle:thin:@dbname_medium?TNS_ADMIN=/users/test/wallet_dbname/".

Refer to the [SSL blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/dev2dev/ssl-connection-to-oracle-db-using-jdbc%2C-tlsv12%2C-jks-or-oracle-wallets) for more details. If you are using 18.3 JDBC driver then refer to this [OTN page](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/application-development/jdbc/documentation/atp-5073445.html)